# Pulling values from different worksheets in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet (wkst1) with hundreds of columns of data. I am trying to get a few of these columns to pull from columns in another worksheet (wkst2) in my workbook.

I was hoping to do a loop where I could use DoUntil IsEmpty to copy the values in each line of the specific column I need in wkst2 and paste them into the desired column in wkst1. One issue is that the columns in wkst2 are constantly being updated, so I need the VBA to be able to pull the whole column (even if rows are added later on -- this is why I was thinking a DoUntil IsEmpty function would be best).

I am ridiculously weak at VBA but am really trying to learn so any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: see here for methods on finding the last occupied cell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: You the man Scott Craner, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in the wkst1 you can select the last row and then use 
`Selection.End(xlUp).Select` which will take your active cell to last row cell in the column.Then use `Range(Cells(first_row, first_col),Cells(last_row, last_col)).select` and copy and paste in the wstk2. If you use Do while loop Then it may take more time.